# How to get latest n number of related model records in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables - `Categories` and `Posts`. The relationship between them is one-to-many. i.e - A category has many posts.

I am trying to get a list of all `Categories` with their **latest 3 posts**

I have tried this:-

```
$with = array('posts' => function($query) {
  $query->take(3);
  $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
  $query->addSelect(array('name', 'excerpt','category_id'));
});

$categories = Category::with($with)->get();
```

But it seems to be working only for the first Category, the subsequent categories are empty.

Comment: try using `toSql()` instead of `get()` to dump the query

Comment: @Luceos thats weird - the query just shows as `select * from categories`.

Comment: what happens when you do
`$with = array('posts' => function($query) {
  $query->addSelect(array('name', 'excerpt','category_id'))->take(3)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
});`

Comment: I tried both. Its still not working. The result is exactly the same.

Comment: When i remove the `take(3)` constraint. All the posts are being loaded for all categories. However with the constraint only the fist category has 3 posts and the rest all categories are showing the pins attribute but its empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$categories = Category::all()->each(function($category) {
    $category->posts = $category->posts()
                                ->addSelect(['name', 'excerpt', 'category_id'])
                                ->latest()->take(3)->get();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Is their any way to eager load this? Though i'm getting the results like i desired, its making n+1 queries.